# Запустить активность при входе в определенную зону на Google Maps

Tags: java, google-maps, геолокация

Как можно реализовать событие попадания местоположения девайса в определенную зону на карте? Речь о LatLang итд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Пишем `Service`, который раз в энное время проверяет координаты юзера
2. При попадании в некую область `Service` запускает `Broadcast` с извещением типа *bingo, I'm here*
3. `BroadcastReceiver` ловит его и поднимает `Intent` с вашим `Activity`

Как то так. Примера кода не будет - не просите. Гуглите, читайте, тренируйтесь.